# Logstash Kafka input won't read new created topic

Tags: logstash

I am running a logstash instance with following setting:

```
input {
    kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => 'master:9092'
    group_id => 'hdfs'
    topics_pattern => "foo.*"
    codec => "json"
    }
}
filter {
    date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["logtime", "UNIX_MS"]
        timezone => "Asia/Shanghai"
        target => "@timestamp"
   }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    webhdfs {
        host => "master"                  
        port => 50070
        path => "/dt=%{+YYYY-MM-dd}/logstash-%{+HH}.log"  
        user => "root"                        
       codec => "json"
   }
}
```

Logstash will read messages from Kafka and then write the messages into webhdfs.
I use the  regex pattern "foo.*" to subscribe to all the topics start with "foo".

Before Logstash starting up I have two topics : foo_1 and foo_2,Logstash read them perfectly.Then I create topic foo_3 ,Logstash won't subscribe to foo_3 except I restart it.

I read all the configs from [Logstash guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html),but couldn't find how to make it work. 
Could anyone give a hint on this? Thanks.

BTW I'm using Logstash 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
metadata_max_age_ms => 60000
```

And it will be subscribing to new topics every 60s.

Refer this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-metadata_max_age_ms